# Is it possible for my app to appear material design on pre lollipop phones?

Tags: android, material-design

I am thinking of converting my app to material design, but at the moment only a small percentage of my users are on Lollipop.

My question is, is it possible for users with kitkat and jelly bean to see the Material design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But you will have to use latest v7 support lib to do that. Chris Banes explained it on his blog:
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Animations on Lollipop like Ripple and similar are not included in the support lib.

Comment: @ranjith actually it is not deprecated. Design lib provides only new layouts which ease the implementation of various views and it is not necessary to use material - so your answer is wrong.
AppCompat v7 needs to be included and proper theme should be parent of app theme as chris banes explained in blogpost

Answer (score 3):

There is no foolproof approach for that. You will have to use appCompat and you can get some of "materialish" features. For others like Floating Action Button, ripple etc. use [Material design library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). I have been using it for 3 months and found it quite useful for UI development.

Answer (score 1):

you can create widget using **Design Support Library** (official)

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

***Before implementation we must following steps:-***

1.Add latest support design dependency - **compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'**

2.Your activity is extending with **AppCompatActivity**

***List of 3rd party library`s***

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompat` (from android.support) and `Design` (from android.support)

These libraries are Google-official